# T-SQL Check string pattern

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just curious that is there any easy way to filter certain string out instead of using the following method:

example: for `AccountNumber` attribute, that should allow exactly 10 digits as the value, like, `0123456789`,

So for the query I made like :

```
@input like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

I am just wondering is there any alternate way to write this query? for those value which require exact 100 digits, nobody want to count while keep pasting [0-9], right? I notice there is something in C# like ^(\d{10})$, but I cannot find such matching method in TSQL, does this similar method exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
@input like REPLICATE('[0-9]',10) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
```

The explicit collate clause is because in some collations the range will match [things that aren't strictly digits.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149947/3690)

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is fine.  You can also write this as:

```
where len(AccountNumber) = 10 and AccountNumber not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

That is, the length is 10 and it contains no characters that are not digits.